# How to insert Captcha into HTML form?

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, captcha

I am looking for a Captcha for my Spring project.But the page-format should be HTML.Also my project does not have web.xml, so I should handle servlet-registration with annotations.

Do you have any suggestions?It will be very appreciated if you share also code.

Thanks in advance

Note: I shouldn't use Google's recaptcha

Comment: [here -spring-recaptcha-v2-form-validation-](https://kielczewski.eu/2015/07/spring-recaptcha-v2-form-validation/) you find a great tutorial

Comment: I am able to use Thymeleaf